# WinDbg remote debugger protocol

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I'd like to build a client for `dbgsrv.exe`. I'd like to know if there's a spec on the protocol that it uses and if there are any (open source?) libraries that are able to communicate with it for a remote debugging session.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: See https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-07/Stewart/Presentation/bh-usa-07-stewart.pdf for a presentation that seems to describe the protocol.

Also browsing through **the source code of [ReactOS](http://gr8os.googlecode.com/svn-history/r66/branches/0.2-devel/kernel/kd.cpp), seems to have a some of the implementation of the protocol**. Also  Microsoft Research's Singularity OS may have a debugger available in source. I know most of the OS is managed, however it will I suspect have the source code for its  remote debugger communication.

Microsoft [MDBG is a managed debugger with source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861.aspx) . This may have the answer

Comment: Great answer. But I don't think it'll work for me (forgot to mention, need to use it to debug native x64 applications). Thanks, though!

Comment: Singularity would also be my best idea. It used WinDbg remote debugging for managed Sing# (or whatever that languages name was).

Answer (score 0):

There's at least one [summary](https://www.developerfusion.com/article/84367/kernel-and-remote-debuggers/) of debugger internals and the serial protocol on the net.